# Resolving promise without await

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Is it possible to resolve a promise without await function? I've read it's possible using setTimeout function, however I don't know how long will it take to respond. When I write to console.log it seems to  work even without await function, was wondering how it works with console.log but not when assigning the result

```
const shareName="myshare";
const shareClient = serviceClient.getShareClient(shareName);
let shareExists:boolean;
//The below line doesn't return the result if I don't use await and shareExists will be undefined
shareClient.exists().then((result)=>{shareExists = result;}).catch((error)=>console.log(error.message));

//But when I write to console.log, it works fine without await, I can see the result in console
shareClient.exists().then((result)=>console.log(result)).catch((error)=>console.log(error.message))
```

I'm also having issues with resolving the result in a foreach loop. In the then function I'm trying to concatenate the files that are uploaded, however i'm getting empty fileList.

```
let fileList = "";
files.forEach(file => {
    let bufferContent = Buffer.from(file.fileContent,'base64');
    fileClient.uploadData(bufferContent)
        .then(()=>{fileList+=file.fileName;fileList += ";"})
        .catch((error)=>{this.showError(error,"processFile")});
});
```

I tried adding async/await as below but the same behaviour.

```
files.forEach(async file => {
    let bufferContent = Buffer.from(file.fileContent,'base64');
    await fileClient.uploadData(bufferContent)
        .then(()=>{fileList+=file.fileName;fileList += ";"})
        .catch((error)=>{this.showError(error,"processFile")});
});
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: For starters, you are misusing await. You don't use await *and* .then. Use await *instead of* .then. Secondly the comments in the first code section do not make sense. You keep talking about await but aren't using it in the code. Also, there is no way that console.log is showing you a value but it doesn't work for assigning to shareExists. Something is awry there. Finally, await and .then are exactly the same functionally. await is just "syntactic sugar" to replace .then. So you can use either interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks @seesharper for your reply. Pardon my basic knowledge as I'm new to typescript and Promise. This is what I tried. `export async function main() {shareClient.exists().then((result)=>{shareExists = result;}).catch((error)=>console.log(error.message)); console.log("after:" + shareExists);}` When I try to write the value of shareExists without await it prints undefined, if I put await, then it prints fine. But if I try `shareClient.exists().then((result)=>console.log(result)).catch((error)=>console.log(error.message));`, I can see the result in console output even without await

Comment: @seesharper If you see my question, within foreach,I did try resolving the promise in the then function with no await. I would have expected the "then" function to update the list of files once processed, but that's not happening. I'm getting an empty list